# FFmpeg end of filter semicolon being ignored when evaluating chained filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to FFmepg so please forgive me if the terminology is wrong.

I would like to add text and audio to an existing video file. I'm chaining together 2 `drawText`s, then in a different filter, I want to merge audio tracks of the original source video and some background music.

`ffmpeg -i sourceNoText.mp4 -i backgroundMusic.mp3 -filter_complex "drawtext=enable='between(t,0,3.5)':fontfile=burbank.ttf:text='Your name - PETER':fontsize=90:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-th-(h/10)-20):fontcolor='White', drawtext=enable='between(t,11.5,14.75)':fontfile=burbank.ttf:text='You couldn't have done it without Peter':fontcolor='White':fontsize=90:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-th-(h/10)-20);[0:a][1:a]amerge,pan=stero:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[outMergedAudio]" -map 0:v -map "[outMergedAudio]" -c:a aac edited.mp4`

My understanding is filters are separated by a semicolon, yet when I try to do the audio merging, that portion of the command is being interpreted in the `drawtext` filter.

```
[drawtext @ 0000020fe395bec0] Cannot find color 'c0<c0+c2'
[drawtext @ 0000020fe395bec0] Unable to parse option value "c0<c0+c2" as color
[drawtext @ 0000020fe395bec0] Cannot find color 'c0<c0+c2'
[drawtext @ 0000020fe395bec0] Unable to parse option value "c0<c0+c2" as color
[drawtext @ 0000020fe395bec0] Error setting option fontcolor to value c0<c0+c2.
[Parsed_drawtext_1 @ 0000020fe395ad00] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000020fe3892e00] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'enable=between(t,11.5,14.75):fontfile=burbank.ttf:text=You couldnt have done it without Peter:fontcolor=White:fontsize=90:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-th-(h/10)-20);[0:a][1:a]amerge,pan=stero:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[outMergedAudio]'
Error initializing complex filters.
```

Running without the audio filter works well, so I don't believe there to be a syntax error. What am I missing? Specifying an input and output stream for the drawText chain still produces the same problem.

I'm using ffmpeg version 4.2.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't spot any error after a glance. Shift the audio filters to the front and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a single quote in the text string of your 2nd drawtext, enclosed in single quotes, that's throwing off some parser state. Enclose the text in escaped double quotes and escape the single quote within.

Additionally, the pan syntax is deprecated.

`ffmpeg -i sourceNoText.mp4 -i backgroundMusic.mp3 -filter_complex "drawtext=enable='between(t,0,3.5)':fontfile=burbank.ttf:text='Your name - PETER':fontsize=90:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-th-(h/10)-20):fontcolor='White', drawtext=enable='between(t,11.5,14.75)':fontfile=burbank.ttf:text=\"You couldn\'t have done it without Peter\":fontcolor='White':fontsize=90:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-th-(h/10)-20);[0:a][1:a]amerge,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[outMergedAudio]" -map 0:v -map "[outMergedAudio]" -c:a aac edited.mp4`

Comment: That makes perfect sense - thank you very much. I feel a bit silly.

Comment: When I went to use this, the rest of the command was being evaluated as text. Changing to single quotes for the string resulted in it not knowing what "couldn\'t" was. The easy solution was just to move my text option to the end of the statement and replace with `\\\'`. Thanks again :)